# Index inference on a DynamoDB PartiQL select statement

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, partiql

When doing a PartiQL `select` statement over a DynamoDB table:

1. Do we need to explicitly define which index to use, or can that be inferred from the `WHERE` condition? I.e, if an index is not defined on the `FROM` but the condition uses an indexed column with an equality comparison, is that index used automatically to perform a `query` instead of a `scan`?
2. In a related question, is there any way to see the "query/scan plan" used by a PartiQL `select`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically infer based on the where condition.
Below is the documentation which clearly mentions that.

[PartiQL Select Statment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html)